# When to use “one other” and “each other”

Tags: difference

According to one resource online, it said that “one other” refers to two people/two groups of people interacting.

Also said that: “Each other” means more than two people/two groups of people interacting.

Some resources agree while others are contradicting.
Please give some example sentences too.

Comment: It's not _one other_, it's _one another_. Both that and _each other_ can be used of two or more people. "The two friends greeted one another/each other." "The fans of the winning team were congratulating one another/each other."

Comment: This could be answered by a dictionary and is therefore off-topic, sorry. Cambridge says this "We use each other and one another to show that each person in a group of two or more people does something to the others. There is very little difference between each other and one another and we can normally use them in the same places. Each other is more common than one another".

Comment: @Alstrabee please give the link,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*each other* is more strictly reciprocal than *one another*.

> In the Holi festival, people throw colors at *one another*.

Everyone throws at someone, but there may not be a pair who throw at *each other*.  (For this reason, I would not use *one another* for only two.)

Comment: So when you say each other, that means that this action is always repeated with only two people?

Comment: And when you say one another, means that the action is repeated with two or more people? But, those people are not necessarily the same?

Comment: *Each other* can apply to any number of people, but suggests either that it applies to every pair among those people (“We all know each other's names” = everyone in the group knows the names of all in the group) or that the group is paired off and the pairings may shift (“Everybody's kissing each other” in a song about an orgy).  But please do not assume that every native English-speaker agrees with me!

Answer (score 0):

I personally feel that one other is like one person while each other is a group of people, referring to each individual person.